# Why is the value or constructor 'handler' not defined?

Tags: f#, extension-methods, oop

I tried to use object expression to extend the IDelegateEvent, but in fsi there was an error  FS0039: The value or constructor 'handler' is not defined.

My codes are as follows:

```
type IDelegateEvent<'Del when 'Del:> Delegate> with
member this.Subscribe hanlder  = 
    do this.AddHandler(handler)
    { new IDisposable with 
        member x.Dispose() = 
            this.RemoveHandler(handler) }
```

And the reference is Matthew Podwysocki's Blog:http://weblogs.asp.net/podwysocki/archive/2009/08/21/f-first-class-events-creating-and-disposing-handlers.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of a spelling error `hanlder =`

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342) by removing these typo-related questions, we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?